# Make a dropdown menu on ListView for only one row

Tags: android, android-listview, listviewitem

### EDIT

[image]

It's on swedish, but this is what i got with list view.
Every listview item has a empty Linearlayout that i add a view to when i press the down arrow button. the problem is that every fifth item gets this or i can only click on the first 5.

I dont get why they make ListView so complicated. i want to be able to get a child that is in the list without seening it!

### The Problem

My way to add the view makes every fifth item to add the view when i only want one position to have this "Mängd" row.
Why Can i only edit listitems when they are visible on the screen. 
The child will be static at 5 items even though i got like 20 item....
Is there any way to only say that item 1 will have this and not

position - firstvisibleposition

i think this is the problem with the listview

My code is not understandable at the time because of other things so i hope you get my problem anyways.

### This is my main question

It seems like the thing i add to position 0 also happens to 6 and 12 Why is ListView this wierd ?

Comment: your problem is nor clear, try to explain with a aid of picture

Comment: So mabe the problem is more clear now :)

Comment: please share an xml.

Comment: The xml file involves a couple of more things and have more features but okaj

Comment: I will rewrite the question because i dont think my problem is clear